# Why does checkpointing impact latency so much?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm observing that having checkpointing, while using a memory backend, causes an unexpected increase in the observed latencies.

Consider the following checkpoint:

```
2019-02-27 15:35:46,322 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Triggering checkpoint 2 @ 1551281746322 for job a80597b3312f0704beed75397c371bf5.
2019-02-27 15:35:46,326 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackend     - Heap backend snapshot (In-Memory Stream Factory, synchronous part) in thread Thread[KeyedProcess -> Map -> Sink: Unnamed (1/1),5,Flink Task Threads] took 0 ms.
2019-02-27 15:35:46,342 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackend    - DefaultOperatorStateBackend snapshot (In-Memory Stream Factory, synchronous part) in thread Thread[Async calls on Source: Custom Source -> Map -> Timestamps/Watermarks (1/1),5,Flink Task Threads] took 2 ms.
2019-02-27 15:35:46,346 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackend    - DefaultOperatorStateBackend snapshot (In-Memory Stream Factory, asynchronous part) in thread Thread[pool-14-thread-2,5,Flink Task Threads] took 3 ms.
2019-02-27 15:35:46,351 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackend     - Heap backend snapshot (In-Memory Stream Factory, asynchronous part) in thread Thread[pool-11-thread-2,5,Flink Task Threads] took 14 ms.
2019-02-27 15:35:46,378 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Completed checkpoint 2 for job a80597b3312f0704beed75397c371bf5 (1157653 bytes in 54 ms).
```

Even though the end-to-end duration was just 50ms, the response for the event injected at `15:35:46,385` only arrived at `15:35:46,905` (**520ms later**). Between these 2 timestamps no events were processed. Without checkpointing the latency at 99.99% is ~15ms.

Setup:

- Parallelism = 1
- Network buffer = 0
- RMQ source -> Window -> RMQ sink
- Injector measures latency using the `System.nanoTime` difference between injection and receiving the response

edit: this is a linear job, so I guess there's no alignment of the checkpoint barriers.

Comment: Could you provide us with a working example which allows us to reproduce your problem? How long is the window?

Comment: @TillRohrmann, appreciate your willingness to help, but I think I've already found the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time is being spent in the synchronous ACK'ing of messages to RabbitMQ (`MessageAcknowledgingSourceBase#notifyCheckpointComplete` > `MultipleIdsMessageAcknowledgingSourceBase#acknowledgeIDs` > `RMQSource#acknowledgeSessionIDs`). This could probably be made asynchronously, like the Kafka connector does.

Because my checkpoint interval is 3 minutes and I'm injecting 200 ev/s, this means that each checkpoint triggers the acknowledgement of 36k messages (200*60*3), which is taking around 500ms.

Using a smaller interval might help having more predictable latency, at the cost of an higher median latency.